# Why isn't none of the contents of the page loading while recording script through JMeter in Firefox even after all the configurations are done right?

Tags: jmeter

I am facing an issue with recording Scripts in FireFox browser through JMeter.

Configuration:

I have the Proxy setting in Firefox set to Proxy -localhost; Port -8080.

I have added the RootCA certificate to the browser.

I have set the Port number to 8080 in JMeter also.

Running Script:

TestPlan >Add >Non-Test Elements

Target Controller is set to TestPlan > HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder

Port number is set to 8080

Start - The recorder is displayed and recording starts.

Issue:

In Firefox, I have launched my application URL in my Test Server.
The Page title is the Application Page Title.
The URL displayed in the address bar is the URL that I have launched
But the page contents are not displayed. (There is no page load symbol nor is the page loading, even when left for 1 hour, contents of the page are not displayed.)

NOTE:
I have tried recording scripts in BlazeMeter App and Google with the same settings mentioned above and it worked fine.
I am facing this issue only with my application URL.

Is this issue related to Network or Proxy or Firewall?
I am using a Test Server which does not have Internet Connectivity and directly launches my application URL's.

Please help me understand what the issue is and let me know if there is any work around to it.

Answer (score 0):

At least partial answer is always in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), either use your favourite text editor/log viewer application to open *jmeter.log* file content (it's generated in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation) or just tick the icon with yellow exclamation sign at right-top corner of JMeter GUI and it will open the log viewer panel:

[image]

You might want to re-try recording using special [Recording Template](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature)

[image]

it's accessible from JMeter's main menu: File -> Templates

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried with Templates - I still see the same issue. @DmitriT

Comment: Also, I do not see any error in the log file.  – Dmitri T